# How can I emulate a SerialStream with a MemoryStream being supplied with intermittent data in .Net4

Tags: c#-4.0, stream

I am working on a project that will use a `SerialStream`. This is the `SerialPort.BaseStream`. I would like to at times replace that stream with a `MemoryStream` for testing purposes and general data simulation.

The `SerialStream` is a dynamic stream. It will stay open and a connected `BinaryReader` will happily block on `ReadByte` until the next byte comes rolling into the serial port. This is a good thing.

My problem is that a `MemoryStream` it is a fixed entity. You have to prefill it with data, reset the `BaseStream’s` position and then start reading. But now you can't add the next round of data.

Is there an existing version of `MemoryStream` or a derivative that will allow me to simulate a dynamic stream?  My goal is to pass the parsing routine a stream and it doesn’t know the underlying difference of a Serial Port, Network port or a memory pipe.

I keep coming back to the basic problem, of how to handle continuous consumption and supply of data between process using memory streams.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something very similar a while back and came up with what I called a `ProducerConsumerStream`. Basically, it's a circular queue with a `Stream` interface. With it, I could connect a binary reader to one end and then intermittently add data on the other end. Worked great.

See [Building a new type of stream](http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=852)

Comment: Thank you for the article. As a workaround I grafted a ConcurrentQueue to the parser thread object as an alternate input source. I will revisit this soon as it is something I've been trying to do for sometime now.